Definition of colligative properties
My textbook says:

[Colligative] properties  depend on the number of solute particles irrespective of their nature relative to the total number of particles present in the solution.

Elevation in boiling point is one of the examples. Is there some kind of necessary proportionality between the concentration of solute and the colligative property? (It's implied somewhere, but not explicitly spoken) Or can I say that along with elevation in boiling point, even boiling point itself will be a colligative property? Since it does depend on concentration of solute particles, but without proportionality.

The extent of the response depends on the concentration. The greater the concentration, the stronger the response-

Check for kryoscopic and ebulioscopic constants and osmotic pressure.

"My textbook" Please provide the full name of textbook even if it is a local textbook.

Check out this answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/72339/17368 and also search for other questions having the text "Colligative properties" (you can use the search bar).

@NilayGhosh It is NCERT Textbook Class 12th. Its ebook version must be available on net. Chapter is Solutions.

@Poutnik Can you please elaborate? As far as I have observed, proportionality does exist in all colligative properties, though to different expressions of concentration (molarity, molality, etc.)

Review the search results for site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org    "colligative properties"

The Merriam-Webster dictionary gives the following definition of "colligative properties" :
.. depending on the number of particles (such as molecules) and not on the nature of the particles. Pressure is a colligative property
There is nowhere any kind of proportionality mentioned between the concentration of solute and the colligative property, although this proportionality may exist.

So boiling point can be called a colligative property? Similarly for freezing point and vapour pressure, since proportionality is not a necessary condition.

Yes. Freezing point depression, osmotic pressure, boiling point elevation, vapor pressure lowering, conductance and stil others, are colligative proprieties.

No, not freezing point $depression$. I know that freezing point is lowered by $K_f m$ (where $K_f$ is ebullioscopic constant and $m$ is molality), but that is proportional to molality of the solution. Say, for pure solvent the freezing point was  $T_o$ and in the solution it will be $T_f =T_o -K_f m$ . What I'm asking is whether this $T_f$  (which is not directly proportional to molality or any other expression of concentration) will also be called a colligative property as it also  depends on the number of solute particles, and not on their nature.

Physical Chemistry,  by Gordon M. Barrow, McGraw Hill Book Company, 2nd ed. 1966, mentions in pages 635 - 639 that the freezing point depression is a colligative property. Physical Chemistry, by D. F. Eggers et al, John Wiley & Sons, 1964, gets to the same conclusion in pages 249 - 251.
